# Error on running Grayscale using Opencl c++

Tags: compiling, c++, opencv, opencl

I am new to OpenCL so I have been working on some simple OpenCL C++ programming. I have written a code on Gray scaling using OpenCL and OpenCV. It has been compiled properly, but on run it gives me the following error:

```
 Platform Found : ARM Platform
 terminate called after throeing an instance of 'cl::Error'
     what() :clEnqueueNDRangeKernel 
 Aborted
```

I have been writing the code on Ubuntu, using vim editor.

The code is around this error is: -

```
 int globalsize[2] = {width,height};
 std::size_t localsize[2] = {0,0};

 if(cque.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel,0,globalsize[2],localsize[2],NULL,NULL)!=CL_SUCCESS){
         std::cout<<"Failed enqueuing the Kernel"<<endl;
     }
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's the whole code?

Comment: If you don't catch exceptions, of course they'll be thrown.

Comment: No thats not whole code @A.B. it shows exception near this NDrangekernel, so I put that only.

Comment: Okay, @dobey , I removed the exception, but now it shows the error as mentioned in the code above, "Failed enqueueing the kernel" 

I am confused about global size and local size. I am not clearly understood it till now that how it works. Its an RGB image, I need to convert it in gray scale. Is the global size and local size is correctly defined and used for that?

Answer (score 0):

just used

```
cl::NDRange globalsize(width,height);
cl::NDRange localsize(2,2);
```

for defining global size and local size, and placed it into statement NDRangekernel. worked well!!